# Unable to remove local changes and merge master of a git repository

Tags: git

I am not able to remove the local changes of my repo. When I try to pull from master.
it again come back to old stage.
I tried to delete all the files and folders from my main folder .
but when i do git pull , it again take me back to same error page..
[image]
terminal snap
[image]
snap of folder structure.

I think the problem is there in " Updating 85980a8..c00a679  " . somehow it is trying to get the old reference even if i delete all the files from my main folder.

I tried remove the files with `git clean -f -x -d` .
Another solution I tried is delete all the files from folder and do `git reset --hard` but didn't help.
I don't need my local changes. Just want fresh repo from master.
When I do `git fsck` on current directory , I got this.
[image: git fsck]

Comment: let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Have you tried `git gc --aggressive` ?
If this cannot solve your issue, what about delete and clone again ?

Comment: git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 13177, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12907/12907), done.
fatal: unable to read c15ef9c820d86676c8946111e651fdf79fa030c7
error: failed to run repack
guptap19 at ubuntu in ~/display/d6c/

Comment: @Ôrel, I deleted everything inside this directory and tried to pull the branch . it still throws error. this is a submodule inside the big project file . other submodules are fine. I am getting error for this particular submodule. I tried cloning it in different folder . it still give same error.